# Share Button layout

Tags: android-layout, android-drawable

ı have to make share button then after click button open samething like the picture.And select what you want.

How can ı do this any advise ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this: http://jsfiddle.net/5cxGb/
And for the tip of the box around the links you can position an image.
Give the box itself a `border-radius` to make the rounded corners and position better the elements in your layout.